# How can I stack all non-blank cells from a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am looking for a formula that will take all non-blank values in one column and stack them in another column.

Please see example below. Essentially I am trying to go from column A to B using a formula:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Apple |
| 2 |  | Orange |
| 3 | Orange | Lemon |
| 4 | Lemon | Pear |
| 5 |  | Banana |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 | Pear |  |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 | Banana |  |

I have tried the following formula, but it seems to only replicate column A.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$9<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$9)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")`

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

UPDATE: turns out the formula above works fine. Column A was auto-generated using an IF formula where any false condition would return a " ". It should have been "".

Comment: The formula works for me.  You will need to activate B1, paste the formula in the formula bar and confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then copy/drag down

Comment: Tried that, and no luck. I am wondering if its because column A is actually populated using an IF formula, where a true condition returns the string and a false condition is set to ""?

Comment: make sure it is returning `""` and not `" "` which is different.

Comment: or try changing `SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$9<>"",` to  `SMALL(IF(TRIM($A$1:$A$9)<>"",` in your formula.

Comment: You nailed it, turns out that IF formula in column A was returning " " if condition is false. It should have been "". Thanks Scott!

Comment: Please make a contribution to Super User: post your formula (along with an explanation of how it works) as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much more elegant solution now.
=FILTER($A$1:$A$9, $A$1:$A$9 <> "")